# After Beta, will I retain my privileges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

Currently, as Music SE is still in beta, the thresholds for some privileges are lower than sites that are out of beta. When this site leaves beta, my understanding is that the thresholds will go to the higher standards used in non-beta sites (eg `cast close and reopen votes`= 3000, `established user`= 1000). Will I lose the privileges I've amassed, or will I be able to keep them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you won't be able to keep them.  Your privileges will be determined by their rep requirements at the time.

IMO, this is a failing of the system.  It was a bit of an issue for the Android site when suddenly we had no high-privileged users (apart from me and the mods at the time), but I expect things will be more nuanced going forward.

Comment: This issue is perhaps one important reason for NOT graduating a site too early (even if the site has been around for a long time and is quite obvious to have the right to live).